MAUI Native android binding issues while compiling the app(Error:Unexpected attempt to initialize initialized java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. )
MAUI Android native aar file binding project compile successfully after adding metadata but when the same project integrated into MAUI app it throws error while running the app.
The errors are like :
Invalid stack map table at instruction index 177: Error: Unexpected attempt to initialize initialized java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.  invokespecial Ljava/lang/IllegalArgumentException;<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V,

Invalid stack map table at instruction index 176: Error: Unexpected attempt to initialize initialized terminalsdk.utility.ByteArrayWrapper.  invokespecial /terminalsdk/utility/ByteArrayWrapper;<init>([B)V,

What could be the reason
MAUI Binding project compile successfully but when the same project is referenced in Main MAUI app
Project did not compile and throwing errors like Invalid stack map table at instruction index 176: Error: Unexpected attempt to initialize initialized
App should run successfully without errors.

What's the meaning of "the same project integrated into MAUI app"? How did you do this operation?

The same project means the android binding project.

And the android binding project which was successfully compiled is referenced into  MAUI project . Now referencing that project  the MAUI project do not compile and the above errors are thrown out

Have you checked if there are repeated initialization operations in the code? In addition, is VS the latest version?

@ShuowenHe-MSFT I can not check the because it's third party aar file. Everything is latest . Build action for aar file is AndroidLibrary and Binding project successfully compiles without issues. But the errors are out there when the target project is run

Can you provide the full error log message?

Invalid stack map table at instruction index 177: invokespecial Ljava/lang/IllegalArgumentException;(Ljava/lang/String;)V, error: Unexpected attempt to initialize initialized java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. In later version of R8, the method may be assumed not reachable.

Is the "MAUI Android native aar file" a library? In what way did you integrate this file into the MAUI project

Created MAUI Android binding project
